# Selecting the children of an element in an AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, children

I am attempting to bind an event handler to the children of the `element` in the `link` function in an AngularJS directive. [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) points me to [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/children/) but it appears that the `.children()` method in AngularJS operates differently from jQuery.

```
console.log(element);
console.log(element.children());
```

Example output from the console.

```
[div#anElement, context: div#anElement, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
 myDirective.js:23
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div#anElement, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…]
 myDirective.js:25
```

Why is this different than the way jQuery's `.children()` method works?

Comment: are you using jquery with angular?

Comment: @Jorg Yes, I am using jQuery alongside AngularJS.

Comment: Looks like it's identical, except for the jquery specific properties: http://jsfiddle.net/9UQSH/2/

Comment: Hey @Jorg, you were correct in that they are identical. I was running into a race condition where I was trying to select children which had not yet been generated using ng-repeat. If you would like to post your answer below, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.element` uses the jQuery selector if it is available so the results should be identical, except for the jquery specific properties: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UQSH/2)

If jQuery is not available it uses it's own jQlite, which re-implements the functions you already referenced.